# Spring MVC Jsoup UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, spring-mvc, utf-8, character-encoding, jsoup

I have tried parsing some Turkish web pages with Jsoup into a Spring MVC project. But I get some some utf-8 encoding problems. Parsed elements are going to save, not send to jsp pages.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(mainurl).get();
Elements newsList = document.select(".one_all_news");
            for(Element news : newsList){
                Element head = news.select(".one_all_news_title").first().select("a").first();
                String title = head.text() ;
               // String url   = head.attr("abs:href");
                System.out.println(title); 
            }
```

And output is : ��al���ma-Y��l��-Țren-Tarihleri
but it should be like this : Çalışma-Yılı-Tören-Tarihleri

I also used these for connection

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "ISO-8859-9", url);
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", url);
```

But result is same as.

Also i add this filter to web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: character encoding filter is not related at the moment with your problem. which site you are trying to parse?